# mysql : date format not working with OR in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, logical-or, logical-and

Whenever I'm using `OR` in where condition my query is putting `date_format()` it's working but when I'm using `AND` it's working fine.

**True Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_inquiry_trans`
WHERE date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2018-08-02'
    AND date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-08-02'
    AND emp_id=2 or user_id=2
```

The above query should display specific date data but it's showing all dates data.

**Test Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_inquiry_trans`
WHERE date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2018-08-02'
    AND date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-08-02'
    AND emp_id=2
```

When I'm using `AND` it's showing expected date data but I want to use `OR` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` logical operator has a higher precedence than the `or` operator (i.e., `and` expressions are evaluated before `or` expressions, in a similar way you'd calculate a multiplication before calculating an addition in an arithmetic expression). In order to achieve the behavior you wanted, you need to surround the two sides of the `or` operator with parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_inquiry_trans 
WHERE  date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d')>='2018-08-02' AND 
       date_format(follow_updatetime,'%Y-%m-%d')<='2018-08-02' AND 
       (emp_id=2 OR user_id=2) -- Here
```

Comment: I suggest you to compare the `AND` and `OR` priorities against the regular mathematics operators `*`, `/`, `+` and `-`. I know the priorities of logical operators, but I have no clue what is a *higher precedence*

Comment: @Cid "higher precedence" means "is evaluated first" - it's a standard term in mathematics and computer science, although I like that analogy. I've edited my answer to use it, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @Mureinik, except that I don't think you need to those calls to `DATE_FORMAT`, because in MySQL it is possible to directly compare dates against string literals.  So, the following should suffice:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_inquiry_trans
WHERE
    follow_updatetime >= '2018-08-02' AND follow_updatetime < '2018-08-03' AND
    (emp_id = 2 OR user_id = 2);
```

The logic in the above check on `follow_updatetime` is that any date would match if it were on or after *midnight* of `2018-08-02` or strictly *before* midnight of `2018-08-03`.  This would cover the entire day of `2018-08-02`.  This version of doing it is preferable to what you had, because it makes it possible to use an index on the `follow_updatetime` column.

Comment: What if `follow_updatetime` is a `DateTime` Type ? If I'm not wrong, it will compare `'2018-08-02 08:42:42'` against `'2018-08-02'` and results `false`

Comment: @Cid Nope.  Compare a timestamp against a date literal, and you're comparing against a timestamp at midnight, at that date.  Try out a query if you don't believe me :-)

Comment: MySQL will perform an implicit conversion?

Comment: Oh...that's what you're asking about.  Yes, MySQL should do an implicit conversion.

Comment: sorry, it's not working because my column type is `DateTime`.

Comment: Well, in fact, this should be working [see this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/902f07/2)

Comment: @Cid This won't work in this case `SELECT *
FROM tbl_inquiry_trans
WHERE
    follow_updatetime >= '2018-08-02' AND follow_updatetime <= '2018-08-02' AND
    (emp_id = 2 OR user_id = 2)` because starting date ending  date is save.

Comment: @abhichavda That's not what my answer says to do, and obviously it won't work, because it would only match records falling on midnight of `2018-08-02`.  Read my answer to see how to make this work.

Comment: `follow_updatetime >= '2018-08-02' AND follow_updatetime <= '2018-08-02'` is equivalent to `follow_updatetime = '2018-08-02'`. The same way `someNumber >= 42 AND someNumber <= 42`